# How to convert a javascript animation to video on the server-side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, serverside-javascript

I am pretty sure this might not be an easy task, but here goes:

My team is creating a website where the user is able to create animations. We are using js+html. The thing is that now the client wants us to be able to send the video to YouTube, thus requiring us to convert the animation to video on the server-side somehow...

Do you guys have any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: I think we're likely going to need some more information on what you allow in these animations. In theory you're going to have to log everything they do in some way that can be sent to the server via AJAX or a POST (<form>), then you'll need some library that can generate your video (this is where we need info, what will you need from this framework?) based on that information.

Comment: I've dealt with scope creep before, but this is ridiculous....

Comment: The animations are 'recorded' on an XML that defines the canvas properties, the resources (a series of images listed on a database and retrieved by a RESTful API we created) and their animations on individual timelines. We are still using jQuery, but can easily change the animation framework...

Comment: Sorry, not an XML but a JSON... not that it really makes much of a difference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you generate "frames" on the client-side and can send them to the server, you could assemble them in a video using [ffmpeg](http://electron.mit.edu/~gsteele/ffmpeg/).

Comment: I never worked with nodejs, but maybe that's a way to create the frames on the server?

Comment: Node can help manage it all, but you'll still need a library to handle the video making. I linked you to one.

Comment: Has anybody actually done this and written it up? 

http://www.thejohnnycashproject.com/ must have done this in some form: sending every (stroke of every) frame to the server, and making various assemblies of the renders.